# Objective-C Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:

Tags: objective-c

I am running into this error and I am fairly new to Objective-C:

I am trying to run this code:

```
-(void)myCheckBoxCellDidChange:(MyCheckBoxCell *)checkBox {

    CellData *cellItem = _dataSourceHelper.data[checkBox.coordinate.row.rowIndex];

    if(([[cellItem actualDate] isEqualToString:@""]) && ([[cellItem finishedDate] isEqualToString:@""]))
    {
        [[cellItem actualDate]setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 8:00:00 AM",[self SetSpecialDateFormat:[NSDate date]]]];
        [[cellItem finishedDate]setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 4:00:00 PM",[self SetSpecialDateFormat:[NSDate date]]]];
    }

    cellItem.selected = [checkBox checked];

    [spreadSheet reloadRows:@[checkBox.coordinate.row]];
}
```

and I put a breakpoint at the `if` condition and the next line crashes with this error:

> Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is the `SetSpecialDateFormat` method:

```
- (NSString *)SetSpecialDateFormat:(NSDate *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    dateFormat = nil;
    return theDate;
}
```

full error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x26b2ffef 0x34ddfc8b 0x26b2ff35 0x26aeb26f 0xb3301 0xc33d9 0x2a30206b 0x2a1b10f9 0x2a5caf9b 0x2a17a181 0x2a17805f 0x2a1af4d9 0x2a1aeddd 0x2a184fe5 0x2a3fb8fb 0x2a1839f9 0x26af5faf 0x26af53bf 0x26af3a25 0x26a40201 0x26a40013 0x2e20d201 0x2a1e4a59 0xa75b1 0x3536baaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`
```

[image]

This is where else its being called:

```
actualDate = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

[[cellData actualDate]setString:@""];

[[cellData actualDate]setString:[object valueForKey:@"actualDate"]];

[formattedCell setActualDate:(NSMutableString*)([c.actualDate isEqualToString:@""]?@"":[self reverseStringDate:[c.actualDate substringToIndex:10]])];
-(NSString *)reverseStringDate:(NSString*)originalDateString
{
    NSArray* components = nil;
    components = [originalDateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *reversedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[components objectAtIndex:2],[components objectAtIndex:1],[components objectAtIndex:0]];
    return reversedString;
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `actualDate` property? And show the complete and exact error message.

Comment: FYI - the call to `dateFormat = nil;` is unnecessary.

Comment: You still haven't stated how `actualDate` is declared. What is its type supposed to be? `NSString`? `NSMutableString`?

Comment: It may have been declared a mutable string but somewhere you assign an immutable string to the property. This is why the call to `setString:` is failing. You need to find where you assign an immutable string. It's not in the code you posted.

Comment: The code in your last code snippet on the bottom makes no sense.  You can't just have a method declaration and dangling code sitting there at the same level...

Comment: You need to show us the .h for CellData.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [formattedCell setActualDate:(NSMutableString*)([c.actualDate isEqualToString:@""]?@"":[self reverseStringDate:[c.actualDate substringToIndex:10]])];
> ```

This is very problematic.  You're simply casting *whatever* this long chain of junk is into a mutable string... and that's just not going to work.

First of all, unnest all of this non-sense.  And then, instead of casting, lets call `mutableCopy` on our `NSString` object so we actually get a `NSMutableString` object.

```
NSMutableString *dateString = [@"" mutableCopy];
if (![c.actualDate isEqualToString:@""]) {
    dateString = [[self reverseStringDate:[c.actualDate substringToIndex:10]] mutableCopy];
}

[formattedCell setActualDate:dateString];
```